# ubuntu 16.04 static IP (Please help me urgently)

Tags: 16.04

I have been assigned a small lab in my univ. and am given a static IP.

And because I need to run 5 computers for my project I am using a router for connections.

```
59.1.61.124 
255.255.255.128
59.1.61.1
128.126.63.1
128.126.63.2
```

those above are provided from the admin office.

I have almost no idea on network and tried to set up but failed.

Please tell me what they are and how to set in lubuntu 16.04!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Isn't that question for your own network admins?

Comment: May I assume that these settings go in the router?

Comment: i also wanna know there will be more to do if i use router.

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE:  This is only for the computer settings.  Your router settings would be off topic here.**

Here are what your numbers mean:

```
IP Address: 59.1.61.124
Netmask: 255.255.255.128
Gateway: 59.1.61.1
DNS1: 128.126.63.1
DNS2: 128.126.63.2
```

You set those in *Settings > Network Connections > Wired Connection 1* under IPv4 Settings as Manual.

This is what the settings would look like:

[image]

Comment: Maybe edit to explain how to open that dialog?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Edited

Comment: many thanks. if i use a router will there be more to do?

Comment: @user601728 If you use a router, the IP address numbers at the beginning of this answer will be what you set for it.  The computer will probably then stay at DHCP when connected to the router since most routers do DHCP by default.